# Prometheus alerting on 2 consecutive failures

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I have a metric which has a label called status which tells me if a job was successful or a failure.

I would like to build an alert that tells me if I get two consecutive failures in a row regardless of time between the failures.

Answer (score 1):

Alerting on 2 consecutive failures will be very tricky because prometheus has essentially 2 different timers for scraping metrics and for evaluating alerts, which are not always in sync, explained [here](https://pracucci.com/prometheus-understanding-the-delays-on-alerting.html). The way that you can kind of work around it is to tune your query depending on the scrape interval and set the count_over_time to twice the time of your scrape, so that you always get at least 2 series of metrics if your scrape_interval is 15s the query should look something like this:

```
count_over_time(metric_name{status="fail"}[30s]) > 1
```

But even this has one shortcoming where if the evaluation and the scrape timer sync in a specific way, in the past 30s you would have essentially 3 scrapes and they could be (fail>success>fail) which would also trigger the alert. I don't think this will happen often if at all but you should still consider it a possibility

Comment: The job runs every 5mins so would I set this to 10mins or so to count 2 failures